# "Segmentation fault(core dumped)" (problem with argv)

Tags: c, command-line, segmentation-fault, cs50, argv

So I tried debugging it and I know it's related to the argv but I'm not sure *what* is happening.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

string replace();

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
  if (strlen(argv[2]) != 26)
  {
    printf("The cipher must be 26 characters\n");
    return 0;
  }
```

To be clear, debug says the problem occurs on the line that says

```
if (strlen(argv[2]) !=26
```

The problem given is "segmentation fault(core dumped). This only happens when I enter text after executing the program.

So the later text is here:

```
  string plaintext = get_string("Plaintext: ");
  string word = plaintext;
  string result = replace(word);
}

string replace(string word, int argc, string argv[])
{
  string coded = NULL;
  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
  {
    int c = tolower(word[i]);
    int n = c - 97;
    if (n < 0 || n > 26)
    {
      n = c;
    }
    coded[i] = argv[2][n];
  }
  printf("coded: %s", coded);
  return 0;
}
```

I basically want to turn whatever the plaintext string is into a code using a cipher that was inputted in the command line argument. I know that I have some errors (like punctuation will not convert) because I'm new to this, but I feel confident I can figure those out on my own. I just want to figure out why it's giving me this specific error.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252469/discussion-on-question-by-user21380365-segmentation-faultcore-dumped-proble); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments section, you stated that you are calling your program like this:

```
./substitution YTNSHKVEFXRBAUQZCLWDMIPGJO
```

This means that

- `argc` will have the value `2`
- `argv[0]` will refer ("point") to the string `"./substitution"`
- `argv[1]` will refer ("point") to the string `"YTNSHKVEFXRBAUQZCLWDMIPGJO"`
- `argv[2]` will have the value `NULL` (i.e. it will not point to any valid string)

Therefore, the line

```
if (strlen(argv[2]) != 26)
```

is not referring to a valid string and may cause a segmentation fault when you use `strlen` on that invalid reference. This appears to be exactly what is happening here.

For this reason, you should use `argv[1]` instead of `argv[2]`.

Generally, it is a good idea to always check the value of `argc` ("argument count") before accessing the array `argv` ("argument vector"). Otherwise, if the user dies not pass any command-line arguments (other than the program name) and you try to read `argv[1]`, you will be using an invalid reference and you may be causing a segmentation fault.

Therefore, I recommend that you change the lines

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
  if (strlen(argv[2]) != 26)
  {
    printf("The cipher must be 26 characters\n");
    return 0;
  }
```

to the following:

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if ( argc < 2 )
    {
        printf( "You must specify at least one argument!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if ( strlen(argv[1]) != 26 )
    {
        printf( "The cipher must be 26 characters\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
```

Note that you must `#include <stdlib.h>` to use the function [`exit`](https://manual.cs50.io/3/exit). Using `exit` instead of `return` has the advantage that it can be used to immediately terminate your program also outside the function `main`. In contrast to `exit`, the `return` statement can only do this when used inside the function `main`, so it is generally better to use `exit` for consistency, even if using `return` is sufficient in this case. Otherwise, if you for some reason decide to move the code into another function, it will stop working.

Another issue, which can also lead to a segmentation fault, is that in the function `replace`, you appear to be not replacing the characters in the original string, but rather attempting to create a new string to which to write the converted characters. However, in week 2 of CS50, you have not yet learnt how to allocate memory for a string whose size is unknown at compile-time, and how to copy such a string. Also, you have not yet learnt how to return a string from a function. You will only learn this in [week 4](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/weeks/4/) of CS50, in which you also learn what pointers are. Therefore, I do not recommend that you attempt to create a copy of the string, as this is also not required by the assignment. Instead, I recommend that you simply overwrite the characters of the existing string, as that is how the assignment is intended to be solved.